# How to compare scale ratings of multiple dimensions from two external raters and several participants who provide different numbers of responses?

Tags: r, agreement-statistics

I started with Krippendorff's Alpha but if I understand correctly, that assumes that ratings by participants are all by the same individual?

Nearly 500 participants produced short pieces of writing then provided ratings for [each of] their piece[s], across four dimensions, on scales from 1 to 5 (e.g., emotional valence, where 1 = very negative and 5 = very positive). The number of pieces of writing vary for each participant; some provided one piece, others up to six pieces (mean = 2).

External raters provided ratings of the same dimensions, using the same scales, for all pieces of writing. So the data looks something like this...

```
    ID  d1  d2  d3  d4  Ans  r1.1 r1.2 r1.3 r1.4 r2.1 r2.2 r2.3 r2.4
1   1   3   3   3   3   abc  3    2    4    3    3    2    4    3
2   2   3   3   3   3   def  3    1    2    3    3    1    3    3
3   2   4   4   4   4   ghi  3    2    5    1    3    1    5    2
4   3   3   3   3   3   jkl  3    1    3    3    3    1    5    3
5   4   2   3   3   3   mno  3    1    3    2    3    1    3    3
6   4   3   3   3   2   pqr  3    2    5    3    4    2    3    3
```

`ID` = participant

`d[1-4]` = dimension rated by the participant

`r1` = external rater 1

`r2` = external rater 2

`.[1-4]` = dimension. E.g., `r1.3` = rating of dimension 3 from external rater 1

`Ans` = written piece

I'm using R so any specific advice for that would be great, but mainly I just need help figuring out the appropriate way(s) of obtaining agreement/interrater reliability for between raters and each participant, and making comparisons.

I'm looking to identify whether there are patterns in discrepancies (e.g., Do raters and/or participants indicate particular patterns in their rating combinations/do their ratings of a particular dimension seem to depend on their rating of another dimension? Do some participants significantly and consistently disagree with both raters? How does participants' agreement with raters differ across dimensions?), but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: I have great trouble understanding this table, because there are many possible interpretations, yet it doesn't appear to conform with your description of the data and the legend beneath it is too cryptic.  (For instance, how are the variable numbers of submissions reflected here?)  In your post could you add *full* explanations of what the column headings mean, what the rows correspond to, what the values of `Ans` mean, and what the numbers in the cells represent?

Comment: @whuber apologies! Should have double checked, hopefully it's clearer now? The values under `Ans` are written responses from participants (here just letters to save space, in the data set they're full sentences/paragraphs... though they're not really relevant to this analysis other than to indicate that where there are duplicate IDs, they are still rating different items)